# Installing missing php extensions - NEMS/ Cacti

Tags: pi-4

I'm installing Cacti Server v1.2.23 on my NEMS 1.5.2 for Raspberry Pi (Raspberry Pi 4)

I'm just learning about Raspberry Pi's and NEMS and I'm just in the process of installing Cacti.

On the Cacti Pre-installation Checks page, I have an issue with three php extensions

[image: missing php extensions]

I am just wondering, how can I install these missing extensions? I apologise for the beginner's question, I do not know where to start. I have searched on google but can't seem to find the commands for installing these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apt-cache search php|grep xxx` to search for the appropriate package names (substitute intl, gmp, ldap for xxx in turn).

Then use `sudo apt install php-xxx` (or whatever the package is called).

Comment: That’s great, I’ve installed them now. Thanks very much.

Comment: @joan I'm working a similar issue, using php8.1, I've installed php-intl as described above, but cacti now displays "Web - No" under the "Installed" column. Probably my fault for being bleeding edge with php (mostly because I'm dumb). Any advice?